# Laravel Spark prject links not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

How I create and run laravel spark project:

1. Create project using spark new myproject
2. set all required directory permissions
3. Since I am on live server I hit the public folder within the project.
4. The page display with two buttons 'Login' and 'Register'
5. When these buttons are clicked it jumps to the root directory, nothing works
6. Even if i hit the url like 'http://myip/myproject/register' the registration does not work.

What I am missing. please guide. I can't create virtual host. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong web server configuration. You web server is pointed to a root directory where Laravel project lives.

You need to point it to a `public` directory which is inside Laravel project and restart web server.

After that use normal URLs without `public` in it.

**Update**

[Correct nginx and Apache settings for Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access/37507278#37507278)