# Routing error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to build a web app in laravel 5.2 on windows platform with wamp server installation.

I'm trying to call a dashboard page by following routes:

```
Route::get('nitsadmin/dashboard', function () {
    return view('nitsadmin.dashboard');
});
```

Following is the route list:

[image]

where my file structure is as below:

[image]

My virtual host configuration in `httd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www\nitsedit\public"
    ServerName nitseditor.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache alias:

```
Alias /nitseditor.dev "C:/wamp/www/NitsEdit/public" 

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/NitsEdit/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Don't know where I'm getting problem but I'm getting following error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with `Route::get('/nitsadmin/dashboard', function () {
    return view('nitsadmin.dashboard');
});` ?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud yes, its throwing the same error.

Comment: just remove the /public from the link (assuming doc root is poited to /public already)

Comment: access with `nitseditor.dev/nitsadmin/dashboard` and then tell me what happened?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud I get an error of `The request url not found. Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 Server at nitseditor.dev Port 80`

Comment: @NitishKumar Have you use `route:cache` ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#route-caching 
if so, try run `php artisan route:clear` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just commented out `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in the file `httpd.conf` present in folder `wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong web server configuration, just [point web server to a `public` directory in Lararel project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access/37507278#37507278) and restart web server.

Comment: I'm getting an error whenever I type my nitseditor.dev it shows localhost also when I type `http://nitseditor.dev/nitsadmin/dashboard` I get an error  of `The request url not found. Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 Server at nitseditor.dev Port 80 `

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong URL, ditch the "nitsedit\public" part:
http://nitseditor.dev/nitsadmin/dashboard

Apache is already pointing the user to the public folder.

Comment: I get an error of `The request url not found. Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 Server at nitseditor.dev Port 80`

Comment: remove this line from the apache config, think that might be where the conflict is coming from: Alias /nitseditor.dev "C:/wamp/www/NitsEdit/"

Comment: make sure to restart apache after that.

Comment: hmm.. ok.. you had the server pointing to laravel correctly before (that screenshot is laravel), so maybe pointing that alias to the right folder would help? Alias /nitseditor.dev "C:/wamp/www/NitsEdit/public/"

Comment: I commented out `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in the file `httpd.conf`present in folder `apache/conf` and it worked.