# prevent the access of folders that are not under public in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

hi guys im pretty new in laravel 4.2 i have a project that stores file in the server and what i did based from the opinion of other people, when the user saves a file it goes to `app/storage/uploads` my problem is when i know the url to the file,  it still have access to the file. for example it is a pdf file, it opens in the browser or if it is doc, xls, xlsx etc it triggers a download what i'm tying to do is when the user tries to access that url, it would go to a certain view informing them that the folder is restricted so far i have this on my routes

```
Route::get(storage_path().'uploads/{all?}' , 'sample@restrict');
```

then in my controller

```
public function restrict()
{
    dd("WHOOOPS!"); //for trial purposes
}
```

any ideas what im doing wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [normal configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access/37507278#37507278) web server has access only to a public `directory`.

If you set `public` directory as root for a virtual host, noone will be able to access `app` or `storage` directories which are outside `public`.