# Fix url in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my code:

```
@foreach($category as $cat)
    <li><a href="{{ url('home/category',$cat->id) }}">{{ $cat->category_name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

When I click in URL it shows the page and my URL is:
http://localhost/onlinenews/public/home/category/2

But after again I click other categories then my URL is: 
http://localhost/onlinenews/public/home/category/home/categorylist/3

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You should use named routes instead of manually specifiying the url.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `/` at the beginning of your URL:

```
@foreach($category as $cat)
    <li><a href="{{ url('/home/category',$cat->id) }}">{{ $cat->category_name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes i added but it's not work it's shows like this again    http://localhost/onlinenews/public/home/category/home/categorylist/home/categorylist/18

Comment: @rap-2-h, your solution will not help, because OP has wrong web server configuration. Also, you do not need to add `/`, because `url()` helper never builds relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong configuration. When you're building Laravel app, you should [point you web server to a `public` directory which is in Laravel app root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access/37507278#37507278).

After doing that restart web server and your code will work fine.