# How to remove public dir from storage path in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using below code

```
dd(URL(env("UserFolder") . \Auth::user()->UserID . "/" . \Auth::user()->UniqueFileName));
```

which gives below result.

```
http://localhost/SportsApp/public/storage/User17/9.png
```

Is there any way to remove public directory from this Url: http://localhost/SportsApp/public/storage/User17/9.png?

I meant Is there any inbuilt method that gives me Url for Storage directory?

Comment: those are your custom methods, there is no way we can see what's happening inside ;)

Comment: I meant Is there any inbuilt method that gives me Url for Storage directory?

Comment: yes, there are helper functions, eg. storage_path() for storage folder, public_path() for public folder, base_path() for root folder, etc

Comment: Can i use any method that returns only http://localhost/SportsApp ?

Comment: @Helper That's up to your webserver configuration, not PHP/Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correct web server VH configuration. [Set `public` directory as root for Laravel project VH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access/37507278#37507278).

The restart server and use URLs like `http://localhost/img/User17/9.png?`

Answer (score 0):

By default users can't  access your `storage` folder by security reasons, they only can access `public`. So if you wish to return some file from `storage` you should do it [manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#file-downloads)

```
Route::get('get-file', function() {
    return response()->file(storage_path().'path_to_your_file');
});
```

or you can move your user's files into public dir and get links on it  using [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset)

```
asset(env("UserFolder") . \Auth::user()->UserID . "/" . \Auth::user()->UniqueFileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver DocumentRoot should point to /path/to/you/laravel/project/public

You could do something like this

```php
$publicPath = 'img/avatar/generic.svg';    
public_path($publicPath);


public_path() // returns the system path to your document root  
$publicPath // is the path using your public/ as root
```

Combine those and you get the full path, e.g. "/var/www/project/public/img/avatar/generic.svg"