# Changing base url of localhost

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am learning PHP and Laravel. Until now I always implemented frontend and never had to do backend and never had to configure apache. I think my problem is a very easy one but I didn't know how to fix, because I didnt know what keyword I should search for.

My problem:

I am implementing two projects. One is called LearningLaravel and the other one is called MyFirstPHPage. In both projects I am using Laravel for backend, Angularjs for frontend and XAMPP for apache.

My problem is that I want to change the base url of both pages.

For example when I want to show the settings view of the first project I have to go to the url

> localhost/LearningLaravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php#/settings

and for the second page to

> localhost/MyFirstPHPage/resources/views/welcome.blade.php#/settings

But I only want to type something like

> localhost/LearningLaravel/#/settings

or

> localhost:8000/settings

for the settings of the first project and

> localhost/MyFirstPHPage/#/settings

or

> localhost:8080/settings

for the second project. How can I achieve this? Links to tutorials would be ok too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create virtual host for Laravel project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access):

```
<VirtualHost some.app:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/LaravelProject/public"
    ServerName some.app
    ServerAlias some.app

    <Directory "C:/LaravelProject/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add to Windows `hosts` file something like this:

```
localhost    some.app
```

Restart Apache and use `http://some.app/settings` instead of `localhost/MyFirstPHPage/resources/views/welcome.blade.php#/settings`

Comment: You don't have to restart the Windows, simply restarting Apache would do the job.

Comment: @ChinLeung if you'll not restart Windows, changes in `hosts` file will not be applied.

Comment: They will apply as soon as you restart Apache. Try it :)

Comment: @ChinLeung, I've tried, you're right. I'll update my answer.