# Laravel Routes to controller doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have no idea whats wrong with my code :/

**Controller File - UserController.php**

```
<?php
class UserController extends BaseController {
    public function getSomething() {
        echo 'It works!';
    }
}
?>
```

**File - routes.php**

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function(){       
    echo "Home route";             
});                               
Route::get('user', function(){
    echo "User route";
});

Route::get('foo', 'UserController@getSomething');
?>
```

**first route** -  On route browser if I type

```
http://myurl.com/
http://myurl.com/index.php
```

first route work flawlessly

**second route** -  On route browser if I type

```
http://myurl.com/user
http://myurl.com/index.php/user
```

second route also work flawlessly

third - This doesnt work at all on either of this urls what Am I missing whats my mistake

```
http://myurl.com/index.php/foo
http://myurl.com/foo
```

PLEASE ADVICE

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Error message is 404 not found

Comment: Have you checked namespace?

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you have wrong web server configuration. Check if Apache/nginx config points web server to the `public` directory of Laravel project root.

Sample paths from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access):

For Apache you can use these directives:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_aravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_aravel_project/public">
```

For nginx, you should change this line:

```
root /path_to_aravel_project/public;
```