# Laravel 5.2 keeps showing public in url only on home page

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, cpanel

I'm setting up a laravel 5.2 site with cpanel.

I have the domain root pointing to `public' and the site is working.

However for the home/index page it constantly shows `public` in the url and comes up with a page not found error.

so for my expected url I enter `www.example.com` and it comes up with `www.example.com/public`

If I navigate to an expected page e.g. `www.example.com/production` the page gets shown correctly and the url is presented correctly

I've got the site working correctly in `homestead` and I've created another site and that works fine - just can't work this out!

here's the contents of my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the standard set up

very confused - what's missing - what can I test?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [point web server to a `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) and restart it.

An example for VH:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_aravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_aravel_project/public">
```

Comment: Hi - yes I have already done that as mentioned and it is pulling it correctly from the public folder

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add extra line into .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

So complete code will be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi- I think I already have that option included ? Do I need to duplicate?

Comment: are you using sub-domain or just domain?

Comment: You can copy paste my code and try or follow here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32580688/1960558

Comment: using the main domain

Comment: Hi - added your .htaccess code and no change. At the index page it still wants to add `public` to it - you can see here: www.spads-drama.org.uk it will add public to it and display a page not found error. If you replace public with productions it will show the correct page and correct url

Comment: as a workaround I've added a route to my `routes.php` to redirect to index as follows `Route::get('/public', function() {
    return redirect()->route('home');
});` this seems to work but not happy this is the right solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,
move index.php from public to project root directory

modify index.php as

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```