# Controller doesn't work in route.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was working on a project that works fine and I now I have restored a backup of the project, the project and the backup is identical, I also change the backup name to the original name and now the controllers inside route.php doesn't work.

For do the backup and restore it I did

```
cp -r project/ project_backup
rm -r project
cp -r project_backup/ project
```

In my routes.php I have:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::get("/password", function(){
        $password = Hash::make('12345678');
        echo $password;
    });
Route::get('/login', 'UserController@getLogin');
```

When I enter in /password in a web browser its work fine. The output is:

```
$2y$10$.grNtTpANndXN0V3/rn9buSO470jPEeVWVyc00rupU6iNt9G.DMZC
```

But when I enter in /login I get

> GET 
>   http://project/public/index.php/login [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 247ms]

in my UserController I have:

```
public function getLogin(){
        Log::info("getLogin");
        $password = Hash::make('12345678');
        echo $password;
    }
```

In fact, the laravel.log doesn't log anything. it seem that this function doesn't execute.

Why controller doesn't work?

My version of laravel is:

> Laravel Framework version 5.2.30

Thanks

Edit: UserController.php code

```
<?php

namespace Ordered\Http\Controllers;

use Ordered\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Ordered\Http\Requests;

use Auth;

use Log;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $user = User::all();
        return response()->json(["error"=>false, "data"=>$user->load("bars")],200);
    }

    public function getLogin(){
        Log::info("getLogin");
        $password = Hash::make('12345678');
        echo $password;
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        Log::info($input["email"]);
        Log::info($input["password"]);
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $input["email"], 'password' => $input["password"]], true))
        {
            Log::info("postInfo");
            return redirect()->intended('/tables');
        }

    }

    public function apiLogin(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->header("u"), 'password' => $request->header("p")]))
        {
            return response()->json(["error"=>false, "data"=>Auth::user()->load("bars")],200);
        }
        return response()->json(["error"=>true, "data"=>""],401);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste the content of the UserController ?

Comment: It would be nice if you post `UserController` source code, just as @osleonard said.

Comment: I have updated the post with the source code. Thanks

Comment: @RdlP Use `Hash` in `use` statement.
you are using `Hash::make('12345678')` , but didn't declare it in `Use` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using wrong address to access `/login` route, it should be:

```
 http://project/login
```

If it doesn't work, you also need to setup web server by setting [document root to `laravel_project/public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access).

Also:

- check `/storage/logs/laravel.log` for errors
- set correct permissions to a `storage` folder and all files and folders in it
- clear app and route cache:

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan route:clear`

Comment: before restore backup I accesses the same way that I have posted. So this is not the problem. And as I said above, laravel.log doesn't log anything.

Comment: Still, this can easily be a problem. Also, set correct permissions on a `storage` directory and try to clear app & route cache.

Comment: Finally the problem was the permissions. I run the cp command as root so, with a simple chown -R www-data:www-data over the project the problem was fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Hash` facade, though you did not declare it's use in `use` statements.

PHP tried to resolve class in your 'App\Http\Controllers` namespace, thus trying to find `App\Http\Controllers\Hash` class which does not exist.

Adding `use Hash;` in the file should fix your problem.

```
use Auth;

use Log;

use Hash;
```