# Requested URL not found - Laravel 5

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am trying to upload a web app (which I made using Laravel 5) to a DigitalOcean droplet. But I get a **404 Error:**

> The requested URL /public/login was not found on this server.

This is my **apache2.conf**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/hotelguide/public> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/hotelguide/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my folder structure
[image: This is my folder structure]

This is the output of php artisan route:list
[image: This is the output of php artisan route:list]

**UPDATE: LARAVEL LOG**

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/hotelguide/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(183): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('routes')
#1 /var/www/html/hotelguide/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 /var/www/html/hotelguide/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /var/www/html/hotelguide/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 {main}
```

**UPDATE: PHP ERROR LOG (last error)**

```
124.43.95.22 - - [02/Sep/2016:14:01:29 +0530] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 500 206 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

After completing the steps detailed by Alexey I am now getting an HTTP 500 error.

**UPDATE:  HTACCESS FILE**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE: CSS AND JS NOT FOUND ERROR**
[image]

Comment: Does this happen with any page or just /login? Meanwhile try a `php composer.phar update`

Comment: @Adrenaxus After I tried what Alexey said below, I am now getting an HTTP 500 error. I cannot access any other page without going through the login first, but even if I type `188.166.***.***/home` I am still getting the same HTTP 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the previous discussion :

- your APACHE_RUN_USER & APACHE_RUN_GROUP are **www-data**
- your `/var/www/html/hotelguide/public` folder owner is **root** and its group is **www-pub**

The current permission of your `public` folder are not good for Apache.
Therefore you have to give permission to Apache in this directory, and to do that, you will just have to type this command :

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/hotelguide/
```

Comment: Please refer the screenshot in the new update. All the required css and js files are in the public/bower_components/adminlte folder

Comment: Can you try to access it with the capital letters & see if it's working ? `http://188.166.***.***/bower_components/AdminLTE/bootstrap/c‌​ss/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: `GET http://188.166.***.***/bower_components/adminlte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css home:18` There is no error 404, only an error in the GET method

Comment: Di you try with or without the capital letters ? If there is no 404, what is the error you have ?

Comment: I tried with the capital letters. Earlier in the Developer Tools console, the error was: `http://188.166.***.***/bower_components/adminlte/bootstrap/c‌​ss/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` but now the error is: `GET http://188.166.***.***/bower_components/AdminLTE/bootstrap/c‌​ss/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: please apologize my confusion. I am still getting a 404 error. I got confused reading with something else. Summary: I am getting the 404 error with capital and simple letters both

Comment: do you think it has something to do with permissions?

Comment: Can you try to edit `/var/www/html/hotelguide/public/.htaccess` and add `RewriteBase /hotelguide/` just below the `RewriteEngine On` please ?

Comment: Hi, again. When I did the edit you proposed, the webpage stopped working again (no worries I took a backup of the original htaccess). Again I got a 500 Internal Server error and when I checked the server logs: `[core:error] [pid 2086] [client 112.134.83.66:35238] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace` Sorry for the late reply

Comment: Strange... Can you try to edit `/var/www/html/hotelguide/public/.htaccess` again, but this time add `RewriteBase /` just below the `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: Like you said, I added `RewriteBase /` (without the hotelguide) right under `RewriteEngine On`. This time, the page loaded without any server error, but the CSS and JS are still 404.

Comment: you were right from the beginning. I **completely** forgot that Linux servers were case sensitive. I tried `<IfModule mod_speling.c></IfModule>` but that didn't work either, for some reason. So I just went to the FTP and changed _AdminLTE_ to _adminlte_ . Thanks for all your help. It was much appreciated.

Comment: You too! :) Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [point Apache to a `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) and restart it:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/hotelguide/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/hotelguide/public">
```

After doing that use `/login` URL instead of `/public/login`.

Comment: I tried that. Now I am getting an HTTP 500 error saying `188.166.***.*** is not working. Cannot handle the request`. I thought this was due to permissions, but even after I ran `sudo chmod -R o+w hotelguide` and `sudo chmod -R o+w hotelguide/storage` I am still getting the same HTTP 500 error

Comment: Please post last error message instead of stack trace.

Comment: the stack trace is the last messages logged in the laravel log. If the error is not being logged, is there a problem with the permissions?

Comment: Can you check if your public folder is owned by www-data ? And provide the content of the .htaccess file (if existing) located in /var/www/html/hotelguide/public/ folder.

Comment: @Julqas I updated the question with the .htaccess file as requested. I am not sure how I could check if the public folder is owned by www-data

Comment: Can you provide the content of .htaccess file located in `/var/www/html/hotelguide/` this time please ? To check the owned of a folder, in CLI you can do `ls -l /var/www/html/hotelguide/` and check owner and group (something like `drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data  4096 Aug 17 09:13 public`), or if you are using a graphic FTP client, I think doing a right click on folder then "properties", something like that can do the trick.

Comment: @Julqas When I ran `ls -l` I saw that the public folder is owned by `www-pub` as shown in this: `drwxr-sr-x  3 root www-pub   4096 Sep  2 11:48 public`. Also, I'm sorry but there is no .htaccess file in `var/www/html/hotelguide` The .htaccess folder is only present in the public folder

Comment: Not exactly, the owner of your public folder is `root`, and the group is `www-pub`. Can you provide the result of this command `groups www-pub` please ? And the value configured in your `/etc/apache2/envvars` file for APACHE_RUN_USER & APACHE_RUN_GROUP.

Comment: @Julqas When I try to run `groups www-pub` I get an error saying `groups: www-pub: no such user` and in the envvars file, `APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data` and `APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data`

Comment: If you can check what are the best practice in terms of permissions & such for Laravel, but doing a `chown  -R root:www-data /var/www/html/hotelguide/` would do a lot more sense for me here..
If it's not working maybe you can try `chown  -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/hotelguide/`

Comment: @Julqas You are a God. The second code worked. For some reason none of my css files and js files are being, loaded though. When I check the inspector it says `http://188.166.***.***/bower_components/adminlte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` I don't understand this because bower_components is inside my `hotelguide/public` folder and the public folder is the root of my site

Comment: Glad it helped :) I will write an answer for next people to find directly the answer. 
For the css & js file, is the file `/var/www/html/hotelguide/public/bower_components/adminlte/bootstrap/c‌​ss/bootstrap.min.css` exists for example ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the location of your project. Add the configuration in `httpd.conf`
as given below:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/project_name/public">
   Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```