# Routes not working on server using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I'm deploying a webapp to a digitalOcean droplet and it displays the home route just fine. I have dependencies installed, Apache conf pointing to laravel's public folder, permissions given to `www-data` so Apache can use the folder but, when I try to access a link defined in the site, already defined in the routes file, for example `/about` I get a 404 error.
 
Why could this be?
The droplet's runs Ubuntu 16.04, I have Apache and php7.
I was reading this two posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286925/requested-url-not-found-laravel-5/39289906) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458080/the-requested-url-projectname-users-was-not-found-on-this-server-laravel?rq=1) but got no luck
**My apache conf file is**

```
<Directory /var/www/html/analizalabs/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**My sites-available file**

```
 ServerAdmin tecnofunk@cryptolab.net
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/analizalabs/public/
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

**Part of my routes file**

```
Route::get('/','PagesController@home');
Route::get('/about','PagesController@about');
Route::get('/contact','PagesController@contact');
```

**My htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**Permissions like...**

```
drwxrwxr-x   8 www-data dev   4096 Sep  9 21:58 public
```

where `dev` is the group I use to modify files with rw access in that directory.

Comment: Seems nothing is wrong with you, You sure about 404? maybe its not find controller or method. Double check PagesController namespace ( should be App\Http\Controllers )

Comment: sure about it, it works in my local dev. Just checked and controller's namespace just fine. `namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class PagesController extends Controller
`

Comment: What version of laravel you are using? < 5.3 or == 5.3?

Comment: 5.2, sorry, I've missed to clarify that

Comment: Do you get an Apache 404 or Laravel 404? if its apache it sounds like rewrite isn't working

Comment: It seems apache rewrite module isnt enable, try to remove <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>, and if you got error 500 you need to enable mod_rewrite

Comment: try this in ubuntu: a2enmod rewrite

Comment: @lagbox is an apache 404 error

Comment: @MoeinPorkamek well, that did the trick, so, rewrite module wasn't enabled by default,right?

Comment: Yes, you can check enabled modules in ubuntu with this command: apache2ctl -M and apachectl -M in mac ( or httpd -M in both )

Comment: Thanks, if you could post it as an answer so I can check it

Comment: I just move `root/public/.htaccess to root/.htaccess` and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems rewrite module isn't enabled, You have to enable it using:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Note1: rewrite module is not enabled by default in ubuntu

Note2: You can check enabled modules with apache2ctl -M and apachectl -M in mac ( or httpd -M in both )