# How to remove “/public” from the URL path in Laravel 5.2 that detected with technology profiler tools

Tags: php, laravel, profiler, feature-detection

I used Laravel5.2 for my websites for example (http://amirhome.com)

I tried several ways for remove public from my url project,

- Way 1. using .htaccess
- Way 2. using Content Moving
- Way 3. using rename server.php

but **Technology Lookup online tools** for example (http://builtwith.com/) don't detected my project framework (Laravel).

How to remove “/public” from the URL path in Laravel 5.2 that detected with technology profiler tools, like http://laravel.com

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modified my .htaccess in root my website [www.amirhome.com](http://www.amirhome.com)

[image]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Libwww-perl Access Test
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
    RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [point you web server to `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) instead of root one:

For `Apache` you can use these directives:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

For `nginx`, you should change this line:

```
root /path_to_laravel_project/public;
```

Comment: Thank you for your guide

but i don't root access to server, and i have only admin panel to my host (directadmin).