# Laravel url in search engines have index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How can I hide index.php in search engines, I think this is my Htaccess Problem, But I dont Know how to fix this . look at this picture please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [point web server to a `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) instead of project root. Apache config example:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

Don't forget to restart web server.

Comment: i'm work in host . how can i reset web server .. sorry i'm beginner

Comment: If you have VDS or dedicated server, you can edit Apache/Nginx config. If you on shared host, you better contact support team and ask this question. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps

Comment: Sorry in shared host i well change the address to /public_html ? 
and i most change that htacces in laravel public/.htaccess ?