# Laravel 5: Remove public from url, the safest way

Tags: laravel, url, upload

In my Laravel 5.2 project, I would like to remove the "**public**" from URL. I found several ways to achieve this, but I am concerned with the safest way to do it. Please note that I place all my uploaded images / files (Word/PDF) in the **public/** holder. For example, I store them to `public/uploads/myimages/images.jpg` and `public/uploads/myfiles/files.pdf/.doc` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

To [remove `public` from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) you should set this directory as document root in web server configuration. Apache directives, for example:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

Comment: Do you mean when uploading online? Is it the safe way?

DocumentRoot "/http://domain.com/public"
<Directory "/http://domain.com/public">