# How to make public folder as root in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the Laravel framework to create a web application. Laravel applications are accessed from `index.php` in the app's `public` directory.

The homepage route is defined as:

```php
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

But I can only access this from the URL `https://example.com/public`.

How can I make the `/public` folder as root?

---

Curently I've found a workaround. I can create an `index.php` on the root and write a redirect code to `/public` folder. So when user enters `http://example.com/`, it will be redirected to `http://example.com/public` automatically. But still that's ugly. I don't like to see `/public` in the URL. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the directory structure on your FTP? Something like `domains/domain.com/public_html`?

Comment: Please share more details - why not set the document root to that directory?

Answer (score 10):

Do not modify any Laravel files. Instead configure your web server (Apache or Nginx) to point to the [Laravel project's `public` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access).

For Apache you can use these directives:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

For nginx, you should change this line:

```
root /path_to_laravel_project/public;
```

Having your document root as `/path_to_laravel_project/` alone will create serious security risks, potentially opening your entire app configuration to the internet.

Comment: Should I write those two first lines *(I use Apache)* in `.htaccess` file which exists on the root?

Comment: @MartinAJ usually you put it in main config file or virtual host config.

Comment: Well yeah, there is a `/config` folder on the root. So? Should I create any file in it?

Comment: anyway I guess this solution is the best but honestly I cannot implement it. I use cPanel web service and I really don't know where exactly should I paste your codes.

Comment: This answer seems, to me, to be the best one. This will keep your files above the /public folder safe. As is Laravel's intention.
This can be a bit more difficult or even impossible when transfering the app/website to a hosting service which won't allow you to edit your virtual host. So make sure you'll take a hosting provider which DOES allow you to edit your virtual host file(s). Or host it yourself :)

Comment: should i make vhost or just can put `DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"` in .htaccess?

Comment: Wait for a few minutes sometimes ubuntu  20.04 takes time, also clear the browser cache and restart

Answer (score 1):

For running Apache on Ubuntu, do the following. This assumes you have Composer and PHP already installed.

```bash
# create your web directory
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/example.com
# install laravel
cd /var/www/example.com
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
# proper ownership
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com
# create a configuration
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
```

Then in the file paste

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    # SSL configuration, etc.
</VirtualHost>
```

Then run

```bash
# enable your site
sudo a2ensite <your domain>
# disable the default site
sudo a2dissite 000-default
# restart the web server
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Comment: Your permissions are needlessly broad. The web server must not have write access to things like configuration or code, only the `storage` directory needs write for www-data.

Answer (score 1):

#### Domain's document root

The domain name should point to the `/public` folder as if it were your `public_html` folder.

#### Whenever a request is made to this domain, the `index.php` should be executed

You need to place an `.htaccess` file in the `/public` folder that contains the lines you mentioned, especially these:

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

#### Return the appropriate content due to Laravel routing

This way, every URL called under a domain name will start from your `/public/index.php`, which builds up your Laravel app. Eventually, it will either run the appropriate route defined in the `/routes` or return a 404 blank page if no matching route is found.

#### Conclusion

The `/public` appears in the URL if your domain name points to your-project instead of `your-project/public`. Therefore, you can access your starting `index.php` with `https://example.com/public/index.php`.

```
# normal directory tree
server
├── your-project
│   ├── app
│   ├── routes
│   ├── public        <--- domain root
│   │   ├── index.php
│   │   └── .htaccess
│   ├── ...
```

If the root of your domain points to the `/your-project/public` folder and you can still access its content using the `/public` address, then either you have incorrectly set up the Route in the `/routes/web.php` file (perhaps created a group named "public" or added the `/public` URL part to every route), or your domain is pointing to the `/your-project` folder incorrectly.

#### Extra: if can't change domain's root

It is possible that you do not have control over which directory the domain name points to, for example, it may be fixed to the "public_html" directory. That's no problem.

Place the contents of the `/your-project/public` directory here. Then, at the same level as `public_html`, place the `your-project` directory. After that, modify all references in `/your-project/public/index.php` that point to the directory one level above using `../`. Instead, replace it with `../your-project`.

Example:

```
# changed directory tree (when has fixed domain's root)
server
├── your-project
│   ├── app
│   ├── routes
│   └── ...
├── public_html     <--- domain root
│   ├── index.php
│   └── .htaccess
```

```php
<?php
// your-project/public/index.php --> public_html/index.php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

// ../your-project/ instead of ../
if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../your-project/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

// ../your-project/ instead of ../
require __DIR__.'/../your-project/vendor/autoload.php';

// ../your-project/ instead of ../
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../your-project/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Put your **/public/index.php** and **/public/htaccess** file to your root directory as **/index.php** and **/htaccess** .

Step 2: Now Make changes in your index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php'; //OLD code
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
 require __DIR__.'./bootstrap/autoload.php'; //NEW code
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'./bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Congratulations, now everyone can access your `.env` file

Answer (score -1):

you can use `RewriteRule ^public(/.*)?$ / [R=301,L]`   when URL hit domain/public then redirect 301

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect requests to /public to the root URL
    RewriteRule ^public(/.*)?$ / [R=301,L]

    # Rewrite all other requests to the public folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can't redirect to remove `public` from the URL in the root `.htaccess` file if the Laravel `.htaccess` file is in the `/public` subdirectory (which it should be), since the mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory completely override the directives in the parent (by default). However, your rule is also discarding the URL-path anyway by attempting to redirect `/public/<something>` to `/`.