# Is there any way to remove this public from the URL?

Tags: laravel, url, public, php-7.2, laragon

I am using laragon server for php 7.2 laravel. I have tried a lot to remove public keyword from my url http://localhost/myLaravel/public/ by its normal method of copying .htaccess folder in my laravel project directory as well as by copying and renaming server file to index.php. But it didn't work.
whenever i write this url: http://localhost/myLaravel/
it give me following error:
**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /myLaravel/ on this server.**

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel app is not meant to be accessible in a subdirectory by default. You can do one of the following:

- point your domain to the `myLaravel/public` directory, if you want a dedicated domain or subdomain
- move the `public` directory to the root of your Laravel app, as described here: [How to make public folder as root in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756665/how-to-make-public-folder-as-root-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this htaccess code in laravel root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```