# Laravel redirecting to /public/public/

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

In my Laravel project, the `.htaccess` in the application root redirect to `/public`. The page loads and I can navigate through the webapp. But `https://myproject.com/public/public/mysite` is displayed in the URL.

When I refresh the page, I get a 404 error because `myproject.com/public/public/` of course doesn't exist. When I remove the `public/public` laravel redirects instantly back to `https://myproject.com/public/public/mysite`.

Where does the `public/public` come from? I tried some .htaccess configurations, check the `.env` file, but it exist no logic reason for me why the app redirects to `public/public/`.

Can anyone help me?

.htaccess in root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in /public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

.env APP_URL

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

Anyone an idea? If you need more information, ask me.

`Laravel 9.2`
`PHP 8.2.4`

Comment: The web server document root **must** be the public directory. Laravel comes with [an `.htaccess` file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/public/.htaccess) in public already, don't change it. Laravel does NOT come with an `.htaccess` file in the application root directory. Remove it.

Comment: And how I make the public diretory as the web server root document? With an `.htaccess` in the applikation root wich refer to public. Without, the app don´t start/display.

Comment: Your web server needs to be properly configured. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40756853/1255289)

Comment: I don't quite understand what this has to do with the `public/public` problem. The `.htaccess` redirect works, the page loads and I can navigate through the webapp. The question is, why  is `https://example.com/public/public/mysite` displayed in the URL.

Comment: Which is it? "the page loads and I can navigate through the webapp" or "I get a 404 error"? Regardless, perhaps you should try the two simple steps I've provided.

Comment: The page loads and I can navigate through the webapp. But the URL displays `https://example.com/public/public/mysite`, so when I press F5, I have an 404 Error. But when I navigate through the app, all works, while displaying this `/public/public/` in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As miken32 advised:

> The web server document root must be the public directory. Laravel comes with an .htaccess file in public already, don't change it. Laravel does NOT come with an .htaccess file in the application root directory. Remove it. –
> miken32

> Your web server needs to be properly configured. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756665/how-to-make-public-folder-as-root-in-laravel/40756853#40756853) –
> miken32

That was completely right.

In Strato web hosting, a folder for the domain must be created in the "Webspace" menu tab. The domain must then be set to the desired root directory. I found this in the "Domains" menu tab under "Settings" (cog wheel). In my case I had to select `my-created-domainfolder/public` there.

After that `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` and all works as aspected.

Answer (score -3):

You can remove .htaccess from the public directory and add this code to your root .htaccess, this will not let .env be accessible from the URL, and will resolve your current issue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files .zip>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: But why the same code works with another hosting service?