# Laravel keep redirects under public folder

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a Laravel project hosted at https://subdomain.myserverdomain.com, and I'm encountering an issue with URL redirection. The project is set up under the "subdomain" folder, and when I navigate to https://subdomain.myserverdomain.com/panel/ in the browser, it redirects to https://subdomain.myserverdomain.com/public/panel/. Correct URL https://subdomain.myserverdomain.com/panel works just fine but sometimes project users type the last slash and it will cause asset problems. They are typing the URL because there is no anchor from front end of this website.

I've tried modifying the .htaccess file at root, but the issue persists. Additionally, I've checked and adjusted my Apache configuration, but haven't found a solution.

Here is my .htaccess file at project root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I correct this?

I would like all routes like '/panel/ redirects to '/panel' url, not '/public/panel' url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make public folder as root in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756665/how-to-make-public-folder-as-root-in-laravel)

Comment: No, because I cannot edit apache server configuration. Hosting does not allow me to do it. @KhayamKhan

Comment: "type the last slash and it will cause asset problems" - That's a problem with using relative URLs to your assets, not a problem with `.htaccess`. "I would like all routes like '/panel/ redirects to '/panel' url, not '/public/panel' url." - are you saying there is an external redirect to `/public`?? That is something else entirely, perhaps to do with the way the subdomain is set up? "The project is set up under the "subdomain" folder" - "subdomain" would seem to be a _subdomain_, not a folder (at least not in the example you've posted).

Comment: let me explain again. Now, I have a regular Laravel project that I am continuously developing. While developing, I use the subdomain of my test domain to test certain things. There are various projects on this test domain. That's why most of the Laravel project files end up in the folder within this subdomain. Therefore, I often have to publish them under the httpdocs & public_html directory. However, I found the solution, and I will share it. @MrWhite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for Plesk users. There is a setting called Document root in Domain > Hosting Settings in Plesk. If you edit and add your /public folder in this setting, assets and all the other things will be loaded correctly.

I didnt know you can do this for a subdomain, but apparently you can. Thanks for your help.

[image: Hosting Settings]