# Route return page not found Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner in frame work Laravel, I'm using Laravel 5.3
 - I created a new project - laravel-.
 - It run fine on URL "http://localhost/laravel/public/"
 - I added a new route called "home" in web.php file as:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return 'This is home.';
});
```

- I tested "http://localhost/laravel/public/home" 
  but it return

Not Found
The requested URL /laravel/public/home was not found on this server.

Where is the problem? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In development phase the easy way around is using "php artisan serve" command. After you deploy the project, you should configure your server's document root as Alexey suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You're using wrong configuration. You should [point web server to a public directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access):

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

And then use normal URLs like:

```
http://localhost
http://localhost/home
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return 'This is home.';
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Also call it like

```
http://localhost/laravel/home
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the .env.example file in the root project folder to .env worked for me.

Then generate a new APP_KEY using **php artisan key:generate**