# Install Laravel 5.3 in XAMPP Linux

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-5, xampp, lampp

I installed Laravel 5.3 with this command: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

in `/opt/lampp/htdocs` directory

when I go to `http://localhost/blog/public/` I get HTTP ERROR 500

I think this error is due to:

permission `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` folder

I add my main system user (javad) to `www-data` group and vice versa, But the problem is not resolved

OS: ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried `composer install` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find exact error in `storage/logs/laravel.log` or web server log.

If you have permissions related problem, try to run this command from laravel project directory (do not use 777 on real server):

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
```

Also, wrong web server configuration can cause this problem. You should point [web server to a `public` directory which is inside Laravel project root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37507278/1227923)

Comment: If new file automatically created, chmod is 777 automatically?