# Removing index.php from url with .htaccess file. The code is in laravel framework

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, url, mod-rewrite, hide

**Normally the index.php in laravel framework is in the /public_html/public/ folder.
In my case it is in /public_html folder**

This is the code inside my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

> **What changment should I make to exclude index.php from urls ?**

The code structure is as follows :

/public_html/sitemap.xml

/public_html/sitemap.htm

/public_html/server.php

/public_html/robots.txt

/public_html/readme.md

/public_html/index.php

/public_html/.htaccess

/public_html/public

/public_html/database

/public_html/config

/public_html/cgi-bin

/public_html/bootstrap

/public_html/app

---

> and inside /public_html/public

---

/public_html/public/web.config

/public_html/public/robots.txt

/public_html/public/favicon.ico

/public_html/public/upload

/public_html/public/js

/public_html/public/img

/public_html/public/css

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access

Comment: not too versed in laravel (yet) but i believe in the app.config file you can set the base folder of your app which can avoid all the .htaccess hoops

Comment: if you will go into your home page you will see that you don't get it like `homepage.com/index.php`, but just the home page. you don't need to change anything.

Comment: Hi there ! the problem is google has indexed some pages
and the url it has saved in the search results is 

homepage.com/index.php/company/punjab-communications-complaints/4165

I need to fix this with the .htaccess. 
Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

I highly discourage moving `index.php` out from the `public` folder.
I was able to achieve what you are trying to do by following [this](https://blog.kongnir.com/2015/09/25/setting-up-laravel-5-on-shared-hosting-server/) tutorial.

There, you move your code base out from `public_html` folder to `/appications/your-app` folder and move content of `public` folder into `public_html/your-app`.

The tutorial is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

I use this Laravel project's structure too (index.php in the project's folder). In my case I did next:

1. rename server.php in the root folder to index.php
2. Make .htaccess in the root folder:

Insert this code inside the IfModule mod_rewrite.c

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.ttf|\.woff|\.woff2|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|fonts)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours I write below code for me and its 100% working.

Use this code just after

> RewriteEngine On

## Redirect index.php to non index.php

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```