# Importing existing laravel project couldn't find CSS files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, wamp

I'm a beginner to [laravel](http://laravel.com). I had a **laravel** project, in which I have to fix some CSS. I have installed **laravel 5.2** successfully and started **laravel development server**. But when I visit the site, it can't find any of the CSS, Image or JS file.

```
Failed to load resource: http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/frontend/css/stylesheet.css
```

However if I just remove `public/`, to make URL like this by editing page source in browser, it works fine.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontend/css/stylesheet.css
```

Also, if I open the site without using starting laravel development server, it can find all resources but the URL routing doesn't work. Then it couldn't find the web pages except the home page.

I know this project runs perfectly on hosting server, but I can't set it up on my local machine.

I'm using Windows and [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). Please help me to setup the project.

Comment: Could you show me a screenshot of your laravel file structure?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of problem use [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) helper to build CSS, JS and images links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

Also, [web server should be pointed to a `public` directory inside Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) project roo.

Comment: It's like this, `{!!Html::style('public/frontend/css/stylesheet.css')!!}` in blade.php file. Do I need to change it?