# Routing with index file laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to setup my laravel project but I cant seem to get routing to work. This is my **routes/web.php**:
    Route::post('test','UserController@test');
    Route::resource('/','UserController');

Now my `/` works. The functions in it work, but Laravel says my `test` does not exist. I get a `404 error`.

In my `/` index I have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="test">
```

It goes from `laravel/public/` to `laravel/public/test`. But apparently `laravel/public/test` gives back a 404 error. I tried to fix it with: `Route::post('/test','UserController');` but it gives the same error. The only 2 differencex with the documentation that I see is that I'm working from `/` which shouldnt make a difference(?) and that I'm not working directly from `localhost/` but with some maps where I stored my project. Which shouldnt make a difference either. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

My controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller{

   public function index()
   {
      return view('testindex');
   }

   public function test(){
      return 'test';
   }
}
```

Comment: show us your controller

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai See my edit

Comment: You should define an action in the second case. Like `Route::post('test','UserController@test')`

Comment: Check you htaccess working on your server ?

Comment: if '/' works and nothing else does ... sounds kinda like a rewrite issue

Comment: Check: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-do-i-always-get-a-404-error-for-any-route-i-create?page=1

Comment: @Troyer I tried that but it didnt do anything.\

Answer (score 0):

You should then fix it by one of the following:

```
   public function postTest(){
      return 'test';
   }
```

or in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::post('test','UserController@test');
```

Comment: I did that but it didnt fix it for me.

Comment: ok. So is it a Laravel 404 or a server 404? If it's the latter, then make sure your url-rewriting is setup properly

Comment: It's a server 404

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong web server settings. You need to point web server to the [`public` directory inside Laravel root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) and use correct settings.

For Apache:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel_project/public"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel_project/public">
```

For nginx:

```
root /path_to_laravel_project/public;
```

Comment: This did not fix it for me though.

Comment: @Loko you're doing something wrong. It's definitely a web server problem. Check the other settings.

Comment: If I go to `index.php/test`, it works. I had to rewrite

Comment: @Loko if you see `index.php` or `public` in URI, you're doing it wrong. Search for normal config file and point web server to the `public` directory.