# How do i hide my .env in laravel and Deploy Laravel Applicatio

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, environment-variables

I don't want the file in my root directly to be hidden that include .env file of laravel maybe with .htaccess or any other way i have am trying to host it bt i don't want some to go to mysite.com/.env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:w8nPcK6CVaazC/WEv42hf+QOs4zWg2izt1pubH0KnQE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

I have this error from my server.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/skycashs/public_html/public/index.php on line 50
```

Comment: your server should be configured to serve from the 'public' folder so everything above that is not accessible and you can also set actual environmental variables on production if you wanted

Comment: btw that error means you need to update your php version

Answer (score 2):

You need to point web server (Apache or nginx) to [the `public` directory which is inside Laravel project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access)

You're using wrong web server configuration. Point your web server to a public directory and restart it.

An example for Apache web server:

```
DocumentRoot "/project_root/public"
<Directory "/project_root/public">
```

And for nginx:

```
root /project_root/public;
```

Don't forget to restart web server to make changes work.

Comment: is it with .htaccess

Comment: @dagogodboss usually you create a VH, [look here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost)

Comment: Mezenim How do access this VH

Comment: Depending on what you are using (apache or nginx) you need to configure your virtual host to point to the public folder.