# How to get avatar url which are stored at storage directory using laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to get the url of stored avatar inside the storage directory, i am using laravel 5.4.

Actually i am using following method for uploading image and get the url.

**Uploading Image:**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" value="{{ old('u_avatar') }}" name="u_avatar" />
```

In the Controller

```
$UserModel->u_avatar = $request->file('u_avatar')->store('avatars'); // Uploading Files properly in the storage/app/avatars
```

**Getting Image**

I have tried following two methods for getting the images, but both are not working

**First Method**

In the view file

`<img src="{{ asset('storage/app') }}/{{  $User->u_avatar }}" class="img-responsive" /> // Not Working`

**Second Method** 
In the Controller

```
$User = UserModel::find($id);
//For Image
$path =  asset('storage/app/'.$User->u_avatar);// Not working
```

I would like to request to you kindly guide me i am doing in right way or not? In this [reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-how-can-we-access-image-from-storage/replies/183888) the person is saying

> storage is not public. You cannot save files there then create web links to them. This thread is about being able to use laravel to intercept the call for the image, get it from private storage and stream the file to the client.

So can someone what is the best way to store the files in laravel5.4 and how can get in proper way. I would like to appreciate. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`storage` directory is not accessible from the web, so you need to create a symlink.

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to  `storage/app/public`. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:
>
> `php artisan storage:link`
>
> Of course, once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the asset helper:
>
> `echo asset('storage/file.txt');`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have followed the step but  still provided url  does not works  `OUTPUT == http://localhost/lara4/april/public/storage/avatars/20kIkDn1TNuUPWHaQiR1hsceaqpXxKC398v8ChyN.jpeg`

Comment: @Mr.Developer if web server is working properly, you should get URL like this one `http://localhost/storage/avatars/20kIkDn1‌​TNuUPWHaQiR1hsceaqpX‌​xKC398v8ChyN.jpeg`. You should [point web server to the public directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) and restart it.

Comment: I run the command `php artisan serve` then same script returning `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/avatars/20kIkDn1TNuUPWHaQiR1hsceaqpXxKC398v8ChyN.jpeg` but it is also not working, so still i need too point web server to the public directory ? Thank You

Comment: The symlink creates a link to /storage/app/public/ and not to /storage/avatars. Save your files in /storage/app/public/avatars and it should work fine.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey Great Point.. Now its working fine.. Also Thanks Alexey