# send value from dropdownlist to controller laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel, I need a dropdown list, then select one option, and click search button to show the result.

Controller: index shows all tutors to be select, then when select it, pass the value to the select_tutor_page.

```
public function index()
    {
        $tutors = Tutor::all();
        return view('home', ['tutors' =>$tutors]);
    }
    public function selectTutor(Request $request, $tutorId)
    {
        // $tutorId = Input::get('selectTutor');
        // i think should use input to get the value, but it get error with:Trying to get property of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\appointment\resources\views\selectTutor.blade.php)

        $tutor = Tutor::find($tutorId);

        return view('selectTutor',['tutor' => $tutor]);

    }
```

Home page view：

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="tutors">
{{ csrf_field() }}

<select class="form-control" name="selectTutor" id="selectTutor" data-parsley-required="true">

@foreach($tutors as $tutor)
<option value="{{ $tutor->id }}">{{ $tutor->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

<a href = "{{url('selectTutor/'.$tutor->id)}}" class="btn btn-default" role="button">select</a>
</form>
```

Select tutor page:

```
<h1>{{$tutor->name}}<h1>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('student.home');
Route::get('selectTutor/{tutorId}', 'HomeController@selectTutor')->name('select.tutor');
```

please help....

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
 $tutorId = $request->selectTutor;
```

You can see all current request data if you add this line to your controller:

```
dd($request->all());
```

Also, to make it work, you'll need to add an action to the form:

```
<form action="{{ url('selectTutor/'.$tutor->id) }}" method="POST" id="tutors">
```

And submit this form with submit button instead of creating `a href` link.

Comment: dd($request->all()); what is mean? and where i should add this? in index()? or selectTutor()?

Comment: @XiaozhouSong `dd()` is Laravel helper which will display data dump and stop the app execution. `$request->all()` is an array with all current request data. You should put this to the `selectTutor` method.

Comment: I add the dd($request->all()); to the selectTutor(), and it only show [] ..with ..<pre class="sf-dump" id="sf-dump-1234098088" data-indent-pad="  ">[]
</pre>

Comment: @XiaozhouSong that's because you're not submitting the form, please read an updated answer.

Comment: I know i shouldn't use link but when i use <form action="{{ url('selectTutor/'.$tutor->id) }}" method="POST" id="tutors"> ..... i got error with Undefined variable: tutor ....

Comment: @XiaozhouSong you may want to read about routes. Looks like here you don't want to pass an ID at all, so you should remove it from the route.

Comment: Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::selectTutor()....if i remove the $tutor->id from view and route...

Comment: <form action="{{ route('select.tutor') }}" method="GET" id="tutors">

Comment: and I get url with : http://localhost/appointment/public/selectTutor?_token=6tlodVrGPYBg5q1bJaxah2798dwN789YcVTp6z2N&selectTutor=2&submitBtn=select

Comment: @XiaozhouSong your web server should be pointed [to the `public` directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access). And if you're trying to use the route without ID, it should be `'selectTutor'` instead of `'selectTutor/{tutorId}'` and it should also be `post`, not `get`