# laravel adding index.php in URL after localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I came up with this problem, after setting up a fresh server. the laravel putting an index.php right after the localhost when I click a route. e.g `localhost/index.php/mysite/public/login.` how to remove the `index.php` after the localhost?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access

Comment: same result. everytime i click on something its still redirecting with index.php

Comment: This means you didn't setup web server correctly or you didn't restart it.

Comment: i have restarded it but this happens, localhost/index.php/index.php/index.php/...................../mysite/public/login

Comment: actually the system is working when im running the php artisan serve, what i did to run the system without serve is i run this code (php artisan serve -host 0.0.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have .htaccess file inside of your public folder with below code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Which ber server you are using?

Comment: im using windows server 2012 r2