# Put method not working to pass parameter in laraverl

Tags: laravel

My route

Route::put('/users/{$id}', 'ApiController@profileUpdate')->name('user.update');

//profile update function
 public function profileUpdate(Request $request){

```
    try{

        $validator = $this->validatorProfile($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 400,
                'error'  => true,
                'result' => false ,
                'message'=> $messages,
                'data'   => []
            ]);
        }

        $id = $request->id;
        $token = $request->header('authorization');
        $user_id = JWTAuth::toUser($token)->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        $data = $request->only('location','state','country','name');



        $result = $user->profiles()->where(['user_id' => $$id])->update([
            'location'     => $data['location'],
            'state'        => $data['state'],
            'country'      => $data['country'],
        ]);

        $result1 = $user->where(['id' => $user_id])->update([

            'name'     => $data['name'],
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'error'  => false,
            'result' => true, 
            'message'=> "profile updated",
            'data'   => $data
        ]); 
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 400,
            'error'  => true,
            'result' => false, 
            'message'=> $e,
            'data'   => []
        ]);
        dd($e);
    }
}
```

Help me to find my mistake.

My url

http://localhost/project/public/api/v1/users/1

When i hit it on postman it give 404 error.

Comment: `users/{$id}` ? `$` ? `'user_id' => $$id` ?  .... `users/{id}`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to adjust your route parameter choice of naming. `{$id}` isn't going to work, but `{id}` will work just fine. Also the `$$id` reference in the code probably should be just `$id`.

As Alexey Mezenin has pointed out, it additionally would be good to add the `$id` parameter to your controller method to accept the route parameter.

Side Note:

When you are calling `$request->id` you are probably trying to get the route parameter, but that may not always return that. If there is any input in the Request named `id` that will be returned before a route parameter named `id`. It only tries to return a route parameter as a fallback.

`$request->input('id')` explicitly ask for an input named `id`.

`$request->route('id')` explicitly ask for a route parameter named `id`.

`$request->id` could be an input named `id` or a route parameter named `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to pass ID, you need to add it as an argument. So, change this:

```
public function profileUpdate(Request $request)
```

To:

```
public function profileUpdate(Request $request, $id)
```

Comment: @Prince when you'll go to `users/1`, the `$id` variable value will be `1`. So, use `$id` instead of `$request->id`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but still i am unable to solve the problem.

Comment: @Prince you've changed URL and you're telling that you're getting 404 error. Before continue, you need to [remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507209/how-to-hide-config-files-from-direct-access) and make sure you're using correct URL. When you'll fix the web server issue, run `php artisan route:list` and use the same URL as this command will show.

Comment: api/v1/users/{$id}  this the uri i found in route list

Comment: @Prince why the `$` in your route parameter name?

Comment: It help great my problem is solved thank you @lagbox