# Route conflict with public folder in Laravel 4.1.31

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes, vhosts

I have a route in my `app/routes.php` i.e.

```
Route::get('sitemap', [
  'as' => 'sitemap', 
  'uses' => 'PageController@sitemap'
]);
```

And `sitemap.xml` in `public/` folder.

When I hit the URL `http://example.com/sitemap` it returns the content written in `public/sitemap.xml` rather than executing a specified route from `app/routes.php`
Although, `http://example.com/index.php/sitemap` works fine.

I need the standard solution for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37507278/1227923

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin perfect!