# How to use style.css files in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my project that is developed in laravel, i am trying to use a style.css file  using blade engine. but it's not working for me anybody have better idea let me know.
Here is my code sample

```
      <link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
it's tag is not working but when i'm us following it's working.

      <link href="{{ asset('public/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

now i want to now best practices of adding css files and how to include other files. like i've file header.blade.php it hold all css file link now i want to include header.blade.php in home.blade.php file both file in view directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37507278/1227923

Comment: If you need to have `public/` in your assets path you did something wrong. `public` should be your server's DocumentRoot

Comment: how to find where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placed your css file inside laravel_project/public/css folder and use the link it into your view like:

```
<link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I think this will help you Thanks.

Comment: i'm try this code and my all css file in public/css folder but this code is not working. but when i'm try following it's working fine. <link href="{{asset('public/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Dear Rana Raheel Tariq just try to view page source code and click on the css link and let me know the file it is getting successfully or not

Comment: one more thing you are using php artisan serve command or just you are running your project by accessing the public folder

Comment: in source view when i'm open style.css link it's not open. and i'm copy .htaccess file in main folder and access our project directly localhost/mylaravelpojectfoldername

Comment: Dear just try to run project by run php artisan serve command because this {{asset('css/style.css')}} will work only by this if you want for manual access the project you should use   <?php
 $url_path=asset("");
 $current_url=url()->current();
?>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{$url_path}}/css/style.css">

Comment: can you tell me how to run php artisan?

Comment: you can run php artisan serve by using command prompt in windows and terminal in linux just make sure your current working directory is project

Comment: You Welcome  Rana Raheel Tariq.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `style.css` is stored in `public/css` directory thats why it allow second you have provided.

And now your `header.blade.php` holds all your css files so you have to follow laravel's structure in layout if u have app.blade.php or any layout then its perfect otherwise you have to make it own

> Sample app.blade.php (stored at views/layout/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
@include('layouts.partials.header') // path to your header.blade.php
@yield('content')
@include('layouts.partials.footer') // path to your footer.blade.php
</html>
```

Now this is your layout and you can use your layout and your header as well as footer in your view file like i am creating one blog_list.blade.php which is stored at `views` directory

> blog_list.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app') // we are extending app.blade.php
@section('content')
  // here whatever your content
@endsection
```

You can find more details on laravel's official site [laravel-5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4)

I hope it helps you. thank you.

Comment: Thank You for commenting i'll try @include function

Comment: ohkay... if it help than do not forget to mark it with up vote.