# Laravel url showing not found error

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm a beginner in Laravel

I have just installed Laravel to my local server using xampp in E drive instead of c. When i opened this url http://localhost/laravel/public/ its working fine. I have created hello controller but when trying to open this url: http://localhost/laravel/public/hello getting page not found error.

I tried all htacess methods but still not working. Please help me to access controller.

Comment: show your route and controller code

Comment: Can u pls share your routes and controller?

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan serve` on your command line?

Comment: I have used this code in routes.php file.   Route::get('/hello',function(){
    return 'Hello World!';
});

Comment: Yes i used php artisan serve command

Comment: and here is hello.php file <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;use App\Http\Requests;use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;class Hello extends Controller
{     public function index()    {
        //
    }    public function create()    {
        //
    }    public function store(Request $request)    {
        //
    }    public function show($id)    {
        //
    }    public function edit($id)    {
        //
    }    public function update(Request $request, $id)    {
        //
    }    public function destroy($id)    {
        //
    }}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37507278/1227923

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Can you share the exact code to place in which file as i tried all the codes

Comment: The folder `public` should be your server's document root and not turn up in any url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using XAMPP, it will be better for you to register a new virtual host on your xampp's Apache. Just go to *`/path-to-xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`*

And add this code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mylaravel-app.local
    DocumentRoot "e:/path-to-xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
    <Directory  "e:/path-to-xampp/htdocs/laravel/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After that, you save it and restart your XAMPP to refresh its DNS. Then you can now view your app on *`http://mylaravel-app.local`*

UPDATE for sample code:

```
// app\Http\Controllers\Hello.php
class Hello extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }

    ...
}

// routes:
Route::get('/hello', 'Hello@index');

// then you test it on http://mylaravel-app.local/hello
```

Comment: Yes it worked. I have created controller hello.php and wan tto run this. How can i do this

Comment: You'll need to learn the basics first from `routing`, `Controllers` and `views`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

Comment: okay I will. But i also followed this article: https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-hello-world. But it not worked for me

Comment: I have added this code in routes.php file but getting 404 page error
Route::get('/hello', 'Hello@index');

Comment: where did you put your `Hello` controller?

Comment: i added this code to web.php and now its working fine thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You also need to start your laravel server.
First go to your project root directory from CMD.
Than run Command php artisan serve in cmd. so the laravel server is started.
After this you not get error of page not found !