# MethodNotAllowedHttpException path without CSRF

Tags: laravel, routes, token, csrf

I pass a route in laravel which is called by a function in JS and I have no control of it because it is external, this route is a post method since I need it to be that way but it generates me a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` as I do to exclude certain routes of this validation.

**Note:** I have already tried adding it in `VerifyCsrfToken` in its exception vector, modifying that class file VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware to a new file called `class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier` with all its dependencies and I have also disabled the validations in the Middleware but none of them works for me

Comment: Can you please show us your ajax request code ?

Comment: I do not do an ajax is a function JS external to my code, which makes the call to that route, of which I have no control over the call

Comment: seems like your JS function is sending get request to that route, its not a CSRF Token problem, instead you are messing up with get or post request, please make sure you are sending post request and your route accepting post request.

Comment: not because it is an integration, and the document explicitly says that it is a post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris):

> You should place these kinds of routes outside of the `web` middleware group that the `RouteServiceProvider` applies to all routes in the `routes/web.php` file. However, you may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the `$except` property of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware:

```
protected $except = [
    'your/route/*',
];
```

Comment: I did this protected $except = [ 'autentificacion']; but it still does not work

Comment: add it like this `protected $except = [' public/autentificacion*' ];`

Comment: @Mhurtado you need to [setup web server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37507278/1227923) to get rid of `public`

Comment: it does not work yet the error is given to me in this part of the code
 protected function methodNotAllowed (array $ others)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException ($ others);
    }
on line 253-256 in the file C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ resexdev \ vendor \ laravel \ framework \ src \ Illuminate \ Routing \ RouteCollection.php

and says No message

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to add the **URI** of the route inside protected $except.
For example if you URL is `www.example.com/full/route/`
you have to add

```
protected $except = [
    '/full/route/*',
];
```

Seems like you're adding route name but not the **URI**.

Comment: Then setup a webserver or remove the public folder from the route, then test it.

Comment: Please verify the request type is correct? `POST` or `GET`

Comment: Route::post('autentificacion', 'ValidationController@autentificacion'); this is the route